# Looking to Disable Empty values in Color by legend for spotfire

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire

I am using specific column Test with values like 
Apple
Banana
Orange
Watermelon
and some null values for coloring in visualization .The problem here is when i am trying to shown this color by as legends then null values are showing up in the list with (Empty) and color with gray.

I want to show those Empty values in the visualization but not in the Legend.Thanks in Advance 
[image: please find the image attached]

Comment: post the code that you tried, so that SO gets the context.

Comment: sorry i am trying to build a iron python code to hide (Empty) in Color by: Legend but facing problems in finding exact way to do that